# Getting last id when inserting several rows

Tags: mysql, node.js, insert

I'm using nodeJS and mysql to insert a few rows in my database. Here is my code:

```
 connection.query('INSERT INTO trainings (file_id, selection_start, selection_end, label_id) VALUES ?', [toInsert], function(err, results){
...
    }
```

As you can see I'm inserting several rows at a time. How can I get all the inserted id if my table is in autoIncrement?

`results.insertId` only returns one ID (and not all)

Any idea on how I could fix that?

Comment: if answer correct you should up vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put results.insertId values into an array

```
var lastIds = [];
/* you insert data method callback with model */
model.insertDataRow(request.body,function(err,results){
    lastIds.push(results.insertId)

})
```

Comment: I might be wrong but it's not doing all the inserts at the same time (how can I know all the rows have been inserted?). My callback function is only called once (I assume when all the rows have been inserted)

Comment: like:


connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', {title: 'test'}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(result.insertId);
});

put result.insetId into array and return to fetch that... hope it might be work.


reference:
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row